# WPF Toolkit Chart Control -

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, controls, toolkit

I have a problem with WPF Toolkit Chart Control. I can't add text values on chart.

In Microsoft Chart Controls for windows forms is

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

How do this in wpf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend you to load source from [this article from CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196502/WPF-Toolkit-Charting-Controls-Line-Bar-Area-Pie-Co) demonstrating WPF Toolkit Charting Controls and look what's inside.